# Open souce to handle lagre data to create curve graph

Tags: java, iot, bigdata

I here from some one there seems to be a software which can handle large data so that customer can filter data used to create curve graph.

e.g. There has data of the temperature of every minutes from a sensor, and then we want to create a curve graph of one year based on this large data.

Seems this software can filter data based on highest and lowest temperature(will not use all the temperature of every minutes).

Like the way to create curve graph of stock(data of stack is also big, but still can draw a curve graph).

Does anyone know such software? Both business software or open source are ok.